# Why is rpmbuild requiring these C++ libraries, which cause this error?

Tags: centos, redhat, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm new to RPM packaging, but rpmbuild seems to be requiring the C++ standard libraries, and I don't know why.

Here is the RPM spec file:

```
Name: go-github-release-test
Version: 0.0.1
Release: 1
License: LICENSE
Url: 
Summary: Test of go-github-release process

%description
Test of go-github-release process

%prep

%build

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}
cp /root/go-github-release-test/build/go-github-release-test %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}


%files
%{_bindir}/go-github-release-test


%clean

%changelog

* Fri Jun 09 2017 Jerry W - 0.0.1-1
- added text to readme
- add CmakeLists.txt
- add appveyor.yml and travis.yml
- add gitignore
- moved main cpp around
- added helloworld.cpp
- added detectme.txt
- removed test dirlist
- added readme
- init: bump script
- initial commit
```

Here is the log showing that it's failing to generate a "noarch" package because it's including arch specific C++ libraries, even though I have not referenced them anywhere:

```
[root@localhost go-github-release-test]# rpmbuild --target noarch -bb pkg-build/SPECS/go-github-release-test.spec --define "_topdir /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build"
Building target platforms: noarch
Building for target noarch
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.aEY2Y9
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILD
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jOeknE
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILD
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.PZA4L8
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILD
+ '[' /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILDROOT/go-github-release-test-0.0.1-1.noarch '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILDROOT/go-github-release-test-0.0.1-1.noarch
++ dirname /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILDROOT/go-github-release-test-0.0.1-1.noarch
+ mkdir -p /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILDROOT/go-github-release-test-0.0.1-1.noarch
+ mkdir -p /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILDROOT/go-github-release-test-0.0.1-1.noarch//usr/bin
+ cp /root/go-github-release-test/build/go-github-release-test /root/go-github-release-test/pkg-build/BUILDROOT/go-github-release-test-0.0.1-1.noarch//usr/bin
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
Processing files: go-github-release-test-0.0.1-1.noarch
Provides: go-github-release-test = 0.0.1-1
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
Requires: libc.so.6()(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) libm.so.6()(64bit) libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) rtld(GNU_HASH)
error: Arch dependent binaries in noarch package


RPM build errors:
    Arch dependent binaries in noarch package
```

Comment: Are you copying a file out of the root user's home directory into your RPM? Is that file a pre-built binary RPM?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that rpmbuild uses automatic dependency generation using the ldd command on any binaries included in the %files section:

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

Comment: Note that the actual implementation is a bit different today, but the effect is essentially the same: By default, any shipped ELF binary results in automatically generated dependencies.